# Why is Simulink generating .mexw64 files on Windows 64bit?

Tags: matlab, simulink, mex

I am using Matlab R2015b (Simulink 8.6) on Windows 7 Enterprise. I noticed that sometimes, `.mexw64` files are generated based on `.slx` files, for instance:
`model.slx` -> `model_sfun.mexw64`. Why is this happening? Is this related to the generation of the `slprj` folder?

Note that I am using a (big) Simulink model originally made by someone else. I do not know all its details. Maybe it was set to generate the `.mexw64` files?

Comment: `mexw64` are Matlab EXecutable files. They contain functions in C that use MATLAB/can be called from MATLAB

Comment: I suspect you are using some MATLAB Function blocks, referenced models, Stateflow charts, S-functions or simply running your model in accelerated mode. As already mentioned, mex files are similar to DLL generated by MATLAB/Simulink. w64 means it's a windows 64-bit architecture (it would be mexw32 on a 32-bit windows architecture). That's what Simulink needs to do to run the model, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: @am304 - Indeed, it includes stateflow charts. Could you reformulate your comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simulink generates `*.mexw64` files on a 64-bit Windows architecture (`*.mexw32` on a 32-bit Windows architecture) for any of the following as part of its code generation process:

- MATLAB Function blocks
- Stateflow charts
- Referenced models (in accelerated mode)
- S-functions
- if the model itself is set to run in accelerated mode

and there may be others I am forgetting. The files are part of the normal code generation process and are essentially DLL files (with a different extension). There's nothing to do about them, you don't need to worry about it.

See also [this related question](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/90318-how-can-i-stop-my-simulink-model-from-generating-slprj-folder-and-mex-files) on MATLAB Central.

Comment: +1 because it fully answers the question. Just a minor detail: They aren't a DLL equivalent, they are DLL files.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks, I have edited the answer to better reflect this.

Comment: @Daniel if you want to be exact, MEX-files are **shared libraries** (.dll, .so, or .dylib depending on operating system) that export a certain `mexFuntion` function called by MATLAB. Just saying :)